# How to use pandas dataframe set_index()

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Let us create a `pandas dataframe` with two columns:

```
lendf = pd.read_csv('/git/opencv-related/experiments/audio_and_text_files_lens.csv',
        names=['path','duration'])
```

Here is the default numerically incrementing `index`:

[image]

Let's change the `index` to allow searching by the `path` attribute:

```
lendf.set_index(['path'])
```

But the `index` did not change??

[image]

How about invoking `reindex()` ?

```
lendf.reindex()
```

[image]

Still no change!

Note that I had been referencing the source code sphinx https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html: here is an excerpt:

[image]

So then what am I misunderstanding about `pandas` indexing - and how should the search/indexing by `path` be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass [`inplace=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) otherwise `set_index` will return a new dataframe not alter the existing one

```
lendf.set_index(['path'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: OK I had just realized that:  I had specifically been looking to see if this were in-place but did not see 

```df = df.set_index('month')```

in the sphinx.  Not the way I would write the docs but will be aware of this going forward

Comment: @javadba I agree that the docs leave something to be desired. Prefixing the method with "set_" even suggests that it would be in-place, why would setting something return a new instance?